# When I use py++ to generate then boost.Python wrapper on macOS, I got a error about std::string?

Tags: python, c++, boost

The code I want to generate wrapper for is

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Dog
{
public:
  Dog(int age, std::string name):age_(age),name_(name){}

  void bark()
  {
      std::cout<<"Wang! Wang!"<<std::endl;
  }
private:
  int age_;
  std::string name_;
};
```

And the generate python code is as follow:

```
from pygccxml import parser
from pyplusplus import module_builder

generator_path="/usr/local/bin/castxml"
generator_name="castxml"
compiler="clang++"
compiler_path="/usr/bin/clang++"

xml_generator_config=parser.xml_generator_configuration_t(xml_generator_path=generator_path,
                                                   xml_generator=generator_name,
                                                    compiler=compiler,
                                                   compiler_path=compiler_path)

header_collection=["Bonjour.hpp"]

builder=module_builder.module_builder_t(header_collection,xml_generator_path=generator_path,
                                        xml_generator_config=xml_generator_config)

builder.classes().add_properties(exclude_accessors=True)

builder.build_code_creator(module_name="pylib_auto")

builder.write_module('pylib_auto.cpp')
```

I run with the command:

```
python3 pylib_generator.py
```

And I got the follow error:

```
    INFO Parsing source file "Bonjour.hpp" ...
    In file included from Bonjour.hpp:1:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/string:469:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:235:11: fatal error: 'endian.h' file not found
    # include <endian.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "pylib_generator.py", line 17, in <module>
        xml_generator_config=xml_generator_config)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyplusplus/module_builder/boost_python_builder.py", line 106, in __init__
        , indexing_suite_version)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyplusplus/module_builder/boost_python_builder.py", line 149, in __parse_declarations
        decls = reader.read_files( files, compilation_mode )
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygccxml/parser/project_reader.py", line 264, in read_files
        return self.__parse_file_by_file(files)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygccxml/parser/project_reader.py", line 292, in __parse_file_by_file
        decls = reader.read_file(header)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygccxml/parser/source_reader.py", line 356, in read_file
        return self.read_cpp_source_file(source_file)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygccxml/parser/source_reader.py", line 375, in read_cpp_source_file
        xml_file = self.create_xml_file(ffname)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygccxml/parser/source_reader.py", line 324, in create_xml_file
        ": %s status:%s" % (gccxml_msg, exit_status))
    RuntimeError: Error occurred while running CASTXML:  status:1
```

Then I tried to do a soft link of endian.h

```
ln -s /usr/include/machine/endian.h /usr/local/include/endian.h
```

And I got the follow error:

```
    INFO Parsing source file "Bonjour.hpp" ...
    In file included from Bonjour.hpp:1:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/string:469:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:235:
    /usr/local/include/endian.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    In file included from Bonjour.hpp:1:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/string:469:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:906:1: error: '__declspec' attributes are not enabled; use '-fdeclspec' or
          '-fms-extensions' to enable support for __declspec attributes
    _LIBCPP_FUNC_VIS extern "C" void __sanitizer_annotate_contiguous_container(
    ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:583:37: note: expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_FUNC_VIS'
    #define _LIBCPP_FUNC_VIS            _LIBCPP_DLL_VIS
                                        ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:576:26: note: expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_DLL_VIS'
    # define _LIBCPP_DLL_VIS __declspec(dllimport)
                             ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:940:4: error: "No thread API"
```

PS:

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.13.3
BuildVersion:   17D47

Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I want to know why it got these error,seemly I can compile with clang++ .thanks anyone who can answer this!!!

Comment: Don't hack it with symlinks. Your compiler is trying to tell you something. Papering over it is probably asking for trouble

Answer (score 1):

I manual compile castxml on my mac, and there is no question any more. and before I just install castxml with brew. hope to be useful!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what makes you conclude there is a problem with `std::string`.

I can see a few interesting things, though:

- > /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:940:4: error: "No thread API"

  This probably indicates you need to link thread support. Compilers commonly use the `-pthread` flag, but you may need to also specify a linker input (instead?) on your platform. On gcc/clang it would usually be `-pthread` and `-lpthread` for the linker input
- > ```
  > /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:906:1: error: '__declspec' attributes are not enabled; use '-fdeclspec' or
  >   '-fms-extensions' to enable support for __declspec attributes
  > ```

  Try using `-fms-extensions` or `-fdeclspec`

Comment: I have tried to remove std::string in the Bonjour.hpp, and it's ok

Comment: I got that. But zooming in on the messages doesn't suggest an actual problem with that type. It suggest problems worth the configuration of the standard library, such as the two points I highlighted

Comment: I solve it by recompile castxml and before that I install castxml with brew.

Comment: @Praying cool. Consider posting that as the answer, it might help others. Correction, I see you already did :) Cheers.